# how to get table rows which is nested in other tables using xpath in scrapy spiders

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

How to get the table rows which is nested in other tables and form tag.
I tried few codes but doesn't seem to work.

I have used the below python code but not able to get anything

```
def parse(self, response):
    t = response.xpath('//table[@class="DataGrid"]/tbody/tr')
    for tr_obj in enumerate(t):
        print(tr_obj.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first())
```

**Below is html code and in this I need to get table which has the class name as gridTable**

```
<html>
<body>
    <table></table>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span></span>
                    <script></script>
                    <form>
                        <table class="dPage1">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr></tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <table class="gridTable">

                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Solution**

```
 for tr_obj in enumerate(response.xpath('//table[@class="DataGrid"]/tr')):
        print(tr_obj.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose which tags to follow in xpath by specifying the tag in brackets.

For your example it would be:

```
 //table[@class="gridTable"]/...
```

Comment: I have updated with the python code which i am using but not able to fetch any rows

Comment: Can you provide the URL?

Comment: actually the url cannot be disclosed here sorry for that since we need to submit data and then it gives us the results but i have specified the exact html how it looks

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended that you must not use `tbody` in your `XPath` statements in the [scrapy documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/firefox.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom).

So try without them and/or try to circumvent them by using `/*/` or `//`.

Try something like:

```
def parse(self, response):
    # Get a Selector list for all rows
    sel_rows = response.xpath('//table[@class="DataGrid"]/tr')

    # loop over row selectors ...
    for sel_row in sel_rows:
        print(sel_row.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first())
```

Comment: By accident I edited the wrong question. Did you accept the wrong answer?